# When does Android consider a window is leaked?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-view, android-source

I checked the Android source code, and found the following method. 
(`core/java/android/view/WindowManagerGlobal.java`)

It seems that when `who != null` the window/view is leaked. Can anyone explain what's going on behind this?

```
public void closeAll(IBinder token, String who, String what) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            int count = mViews.size();
            //Log.i("foo", "Closing all windows of " + token);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                //Log.i("foo", "@ " + i + " token " + mParams[i].token
                //        + " view " + mRoots[i].getView());
                if (token == null || mParams.get(i).token == token) {
                    ViewRootImpl root = mRoots.get(i);

                    //Log.i("foo", "Force closing " + root);
                    if (who != null) {
                        WindowLeaked leak = new WindowLeaked(
                                what + " " + who + " has leaked window "
                                + root.getView() + " that was originally added here");
                        leak.setStackTrace(root.getLocation().getStackTrace());
                        Log.e(TAG, "", leak);
                    }

                    removeViewLocked(i, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the source...
I'm not totally sure about it but her goes my understanding...

**"who" argument is Activity Name only**

Checking `closeAll()` calling methods, you can see that `who` is just the Activity class name that was destroyed and left one window behind:

```
WindowManagerGlobal.getInstance().closeAll(wtoken,
                        r.activity.getClass().getName(), "Activity");
```

**closeAll() is called if leaked occurred**

It seems that `WindowManagerGlobal.closeAll()` is called when the Windows has leaked already. So, `who != null` it just a check to ensure that `String` is not `NULL`.

If not null, a `WindowLeaked` is created and log is printed. `WindowLeaked` is an Class that extends `AndroidRuntimeException`

```
final class WindowLeaked extends AndroidRuntimeException {
    public WindowLeaked(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Most important is the fact that if `WindowManagerGlobal.closeAll()` is called, it means that the Windows has leaked already.

**CloseAll() calling method**

In `View.java`, we can see that `WindowManagerGlobal.closeAll()` is called when a leacked is detected:

**ActivityThread.java**

```
private void handleDestroyActivity(IBinder token, boolean finishing,
                                    int configChanges, boolean getNonConfigInstance) {
    ...
    IBinder wtoken = v.getWindowToken();
    ...
    if (wtoken != null && r.mPendingRemoveWindow == null) {
        WindowManagerGlobal.getInstance().closeAll(wtoken,
                r.activity.getClass().getName(), "Activity");
    }
```

In the code above, we can see that `WindowManagerGlobal.closeAll()` is fired when an inconsistency is found:

1. `wtoken != null` `wtoken` shows that `View` has an `mAttachInfo.mWindowToken` information. In other words, it is still held by some window.
2. `r.mPendingRemoveWindow == null` there's no pending view to be removed.

So, it is inconsistent. One view is attached (has an `mAttachInfo` yet) but I've already remove all pending windows (`mPendingRemoveWindow` is null)... So, that view has leaked.

Hope I could help you
Regards

**REF:**

[WindowManagerGlobal](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/WindowManagerGlobal.java#362)

[ActivityThread](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#3847)

[View](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java#14426)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! One further question: I noticed `closeAll()` is called three times (two times in `handleDestroyActivity` and one time in `cleanUpPendingRemoveWindows`, can window leak happens in the other two cases?